# I can't execute cross_val_score with scikeras.wrappers.KerasRegressor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, cross-validation

```
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10_000)
input_shape = X.shape[1]
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=input_shape),
    keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')])
model.compile(keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='mse')

model = KerasRegressor(model, batch_size=256, verbose=1, epochs=10)

val_score = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5)
plt.plot(val_score)
```

when I run the attached code normally it should work but for some reason it displays this error :

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
861             try:
--> 862                 tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
863             except queue.Empty:

13 frames
Empty:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in _*getattribute*_(self, name)
864     """Overridden to support hyperparameter access."""
865     try:
--> 866       return super(OptimizerV2, self)._*getattribute*_(name)
867     except AttributeError as e:
868       # Needed to avoid infinite recursion with _*setattr*_.

AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'build'

Comment: Hi fares  Are you sure that's the *exact* code causing this error? If you're in a Jupyter notebook you might need to restart your runtime. If you did `import keras` at some point in the execution history, strange behavior may occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**TensorFlow 2.11**) Make sure you're doing:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
```

There is a difference between `import keras` and `from tensorflow import keras`:

```py
>>> import keras
>>> keras.optimizers.Adam.build
AttributeError: type object 'Adam' has no attribute 'build'

>>> from tensorflow import keras
>>> keras.optimizers.Adam.build
<function Adam.build at 0x7f1ff29e7b50>
```

---

(**TensorFlow 2.9**)

Boilerplate wrapping in a `get_model` function appears to resolve this:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10_000)

def get_model(meta):
  X_shape_ = meta["X_shape_"]
  model = keras.Sequential()
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=X_shape_[1:]))
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
  return model

model = KerasRegressor(model=get_model, loss="mse", batch_size=256, verbose=1, epochs=10)

cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5)
```

Comment: Good evening Alexander L. Hayes, first of all thank you for your help. I have executed the lines of code to check:
from tensorflow import keras
keras.optimizers.Adam.build
here is the error message I got (                                                                                                                   AttributeError: type object 'Adam' has no attribute 'build' )

Comment: What does `import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)` return?

Comment: Tensorflow version 2.9.0 on Google Colab and Tensorflow version 2.10.0 on Spyder. It doesn't work on Google colab or on Spider !!? Once again thank you for your help I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: Odd. It looks like there are some behavioral differences between 2.9 and 2.11 (which is what I've been using). I updated the answer with a TensorFlow 2.9 version that I tested on Google Colab.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Alexander L. Hayes the problem is solved. If I have any other problems with tensorflow while learning, could I contact you !?

Comment: Be very careful about installing scikeras. In my case it crashed my tensorflow installation and had to finally reinstall the entire anaconda.