# AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'build' problems in flask + name 'app' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I am building a flask app that uses weights for a neural network stored as a .h5 file. See the files below:

app.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from bird_classifier import classify_bird
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

# Define the upload folder and allowed extensions
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'}

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

# Route for the home page
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# Route for handling file upload and bird classification
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return "No file part"

    file = request.files['file']

    if file.filename == '':
        return "No selected file"

    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        # Save the uploaded file to the upload folder
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        file.save(filepath)

        # Load the image and classify the bird breed
        image = cv2.imread(filepath)
        predicted_bird = classify_bird(image)

        # Remove the uploaded file
        os.remove(filepath)

        return f"Predicted Bird Breed: {predicted_bird}"

    return "Invalid file format"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Ensure the upload folder exists
    os.makedirs(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], exist_ok=True)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

bird_classifier.py:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input

# Define the classes for bird breeds
bird_breeds = [
    'Blackbird',
    'Bluetit',
    'Carrion_Crow',
    'Chaffinch',
    'Coal_Tit',
    'Collared_Dove',
    'Dunnock',
    'Feral_Pigeon',
    'Goldfinch',
    'Great_Tit',
    'Greenfinch',
    'House_Sparrow',
    'Jackdaw',
    'Long_Tailed_Tit',
    'Magpie',
    'Robin',
    'Song_Thrush',
    'Starling',
    'Wood_Pigeon',
    'Wren'
]

MODEL_PATH = 'model78.keras'

# Load the pre-trained model
model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)

def preprocess_frame(frame):
    image_width, image_height = 150, 150
    resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (image_width, image_height))
    normalized_frame = resized_frame / 255.0
    return np.expand_dims(normalized_frame, axis=0)

def classify_bird(image):
    preprocessed_image = preprocess_frame(image)
    predictions = model.predict(preprocessed_image)
    predicted_class_index = np.argmax(predictions[0])
    predicted_class_label = bird_breeds[predicted_class_index]
    return predicted_class_label
```

So I currently have cd'd through to the file that stores all of the files and using a flask env to help store it. I then run flask like usual with `(flask) (base) ioanevans@Ioans-Air WhatsInMyGarden % python app.py`  which returns the following `` `AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'build' `` .

So I then tried what some people mentioned on similar problems and tried [AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'build'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75088812/attributeerror-adam-object-has-no-attribute-build) and then one mentioned inside of it however, it doesn't fix it.

**Edit:** If I do `python` >>> app.py, it returns

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```